# exporting sas stored process output

Tags: sas

I created a stored process but I want to export the output to Excel. My usual export statement doesn't work in the stored process.

```
%let _ODSDEST=none;
%STPBEGIN();
data x;
  set sashelp.class;
run;

proc export data=x outfile = "//my documents/sp_test.xlsx" dbms=xlsx replace;     
  sheet="table1"; 
run; 
* Begin EG generated code (do not edit this line); 
;*';*";*/;quit; 
%STPEND;
```

Is there a way to get this to work in the stored process?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work? Did you get errors in the log?  Is it your goal to have the stored process return the excel file to the user (what client is calling the stored process?) or simply write the excel file without actually returning it?

Comment: This process is run on the sas portal on the web. So it outputs html to the screen. I would also like for the stored process to send it to excel.

Comment: So when a user runs the stored process from the portal you want them to get a file download dialog box so they can save the excel file?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I would like

Comment: Suggest you update your question with your current STP code. Or rather a simplified version with  %STPbegin etc exporting sashelp.class to excel. . if it is working (creating an excel file and writing it to /mypath directory on your server ) it shouldn't take much to change to  send results to _webout instead (and set appropriate html headers)

Comment: %let _ODSDEST=none;
%STPBEGIN();
 

data x;
set sashelp.class;
run;
proc export data=x outfile = "//my documents/sp_test.xlsx" dbms=xlsx replace;
 sheet="table1";
run;

*  Begin EG generated code (do not edit this line);
;*';*";*/;quit;
%STPEND;

Comment: And when you run the stored process, is sp_test.xlsx created in /my documents?   If not, do you get error messages in the log?

Answer (score 1):

One way to have a stored process return an excel file (actually in this case it's an xml file that excel will happily open) is to use ODS to output tagsets.excelxp (xml).

When you do this, you can use stpsrv_header to modify the HTML header. The first statement tells the browser to open the file with excel, the second tells it the file name.  I believe for this header modification to work the stored process needs to deliver streaming results, not package results.  But I could be wrong.

When I run below, I get a file download dialog box from the browser, allowing me to open or save the file.  I'm running from Stored Process Web App, but should work fine when called from Information Delivery Portal.

```
%let _odsdest=tagsets.excelxp;
%let rc=%sysfunc(stpsrv_header(Content-type,application/vnd.ms-excel));
%let rc=%sysfunc(stpsrv_header(Content-disposition,attachment%str(;) filename=MyExcelFile.xls));

%stpbegin()
proc print data=sashelp.shoes (obs=&obs);
run;
%stpend()
```

Answer (score 0):

did u check with your spelling proc exportd and outfile='mypath/my documents/myoutpt.xlsx' dbms=xlsx or outfile='mypath/my documents/myoutpt.xls' dbms=xls?? U can try with ODS also.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try setting your STP up as a streaming web service, removing the `%STPBEGIN` and `%STPEND` macros, and sending to `_webout` using this macro:  https://core.sasjs.io/mp__streamfile_8sas.html

The benefit of this, is that your code will subsequently work on Viya as well.